# How to get rid of virtual table? Sealed class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, vtable, sealed

As far as I know making class `sealed` gets rid of look up in VTable or am I wrong? If I make a class `sealed` does this mean that all virtual methods in class hierarchy are also marked `sealed`?

For example:

```
public class A {
    protected virtual void M() { ........ }
    protected virtual void O() { ........ }
}

public sealed class B : A {
    // I guess I can make this private for sealed class
    private override void M() { ........ }
    // Is this method automatically sealed? In the meaning that it doesn't have to look in VTable and can be called directly?

    // Also what about O() can it be called directly too, without VTable?
}
```

Comment: No, the method call will still be virtual.

Comment: You're almost right - you need to mark the method as `sealed`, not the class.

Comment: @Nat but as I commented below - this article says that class can be marked sealed http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/01/05/rambling-on-the-sealed-keyword/ It's easier for me to mark class sealed rather than every virtual method.

Comment: @Nat Marking the method sealed has no effect, the call will still be virtual

Comment: @InBetween You're right, I misread the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I guess I can make this private for sealed class"

You can't change access modifier in inheritance hierarchy. It means if method is `public` in base class you can't make it `private` or `internal` or `protected` in derived classes. You can change modifier only if you declare your method as `new`:

```
private new void M() { ........ }
```

> As far as I know making class sealed gets rid of look up in VTable or
>   am I wrong?

Sealed class is last in hierarchy because you can't inherit from it. Virtual table can be used with `sealed` class in case this `sealed` class overrides some method from base class.

> If I make a class sealed does this mean that all virtual methods in
>   class hierarchy are also marked sealed?

You can see IL code:

```
.method family hidebysig virtual            // method is not marked as sealed
    instance void M () cil managed 
{        
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: nop 
    IL_0001: ret value
}
```

Method is not marked as `sealed`. Even if you explicitly mark this method as `sealed` you will get the same IL code.

Also, there is no reason to mark method as `sealed` in `sealed` class. If class is `sealed` you can't inherit it so, you can't inherit it's methods.

About virtual tables - if method is overriding and you delete it from virtual table you can never use it in inheritance hierarchy so, there is no reason to override method and never use it in inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: What about performance? I need these methods not to look into VTable. I know that this is the very small amount and probably it won't matter in most cases and it should be design reason of making method sealed. So do I have to mark every method sealed to make it stop looking into VTable?

Comment: If you mark method as `sealed` in `sealed` class you will get same IL. See:
Without `sealed` - http://prnt.sc/eecpnk, with `sealed` - http://prntscr.com/eecq2w

Comment: Thanks, then I guess it depends on if the class is sealed, then there is a chance that method will be called non-virtually according to this article: http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/01/05/rambling-on-the-sealed-keyword/

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to note is that C# generally makes virtual calls to any instance method on a reference type, even when the method isn't virtual. This is because there is a C# rule that it's illegal to call a method on a null reference that isn't a .NET rule (in raw CIL if you call a method on a null reference and that method doesn't itself access a field or virtual method, it works fine) and using `callvirt` is a cheap way to enforce that rule.

C# will generate `call` rather than `callvirt` for non-virtual instance calls in some cases where it is obvious that the reference isn't null. In particular with `obj?.SomeMethod()` since the `?.` means a null-check is already happening, then if `SomeMethod()` isn't virtual this will be compiled to `call`. This only happens with `?.` since the code for compiling `?.` can do that check whereas it doesn't happen with `if (obj != null){obj.SomeMethod();}` because the code compiling `.` doesn't know it is following a null-check. *The logic involved is very localised*.

It is possible at the CIL level to skip a virtual table lookup for virtual methods. This is how `base` calls work; compiled to a `call` on the base's implementation of a method rather than a `callvirt`. By extension in the construct `obj?.SomeMethod()` where `SomeMethod` was virtual and sealed (whether individually or because the type of `obj` was sealed) then it would be theoretically possible to compile that as a `call` to the most derived type's implementation. There are though some extra checks that need to be made in particular to make sure it still works correctly if classes in the hierarchy between the declaring type and the sealed type add or remove overrides. It would require some global knowledge of the hierarchy (and assurance that knowledge won't change, which means all the types being in the assembly currently being compiled) for the optimisation to be safe. And the gain is tiny. And still not available most of the time for the same reason that `callvirt` is used even on non-virtual calls most of the time.

I don't think there's anywhere where `sealed` affects how the compiler generates the call, and it certainly isn't affecting it most of the time.

The jitter is free to apply more knowledge though, but again the difference if any is going to very small. I'd certainly recommend marking classes you know won't be overridden as `sealed` and if the jitter makes use of that then that's great, but the main reason I'd recommend it isn't performance but rather correctness. If you somewhere try to override a class that you had marked `sealed` then either A. You've just changed the design a bit and knew you'd have to remove the `sealed` (.5seconds work to remove it) or B. You've done something in one place you were sure you wouldn't in another. It's good to have the brief pause of reconsidering.

> If I make a class sealed does this mean that all virtual methods in class hierarchy are also marked sealed?

They are considered sealed the same as if explicitly marked as such.

Answer (score 0):

Sealed means that you cannot inherit from it or override it. If you cannot inherit from class B, you have no way of overriding method M.
As for the lookup I don't think you save it. In your example calling method O would have to look up the method from class A and call it. That takes place through the vtable.

Answer (score 0):

Making the class or method sealed will have no effect, any call to `B.M()` will be virtual.

If I had to bet why this is so, I'd say its because `M()` is declared in `A`, overriding it doesn't make the method "belong" to `B`.

If you inspect the `IL` of the generated code, you will see that the relevant instruction is `callvirt instance string namespace.A::M()`, and therefore, even if `B` is sealed, the call must be virtual.